# Fastest way to obtain food?

Tags: blockheads

I've recently been injured in [Blockheads](http://theblockheads.net/) and I need to know the easiest way to obtain food so I can heal quickly. If it matters, I was attacked multiple times by a drop bear after cutting down the tree he was living in.

I've tried a flax farm, but I need the seeds to replant and extras take a long time to generate. I am smelting my ore while I wait for the plants to grow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way IMHO is to plant a lot of apple trees. Use apples to plant an apple tree. They not only grow apples, but Dodos spawn around fruit trees/bushes, which leave Meat behind if they die.

This combined around your house, or wherever your base of operation is,can lead to a pretty stable food supply.